# Laravel 5.5 Event Not Firing

Tags: laravel, events

I'm using laravel 5.5. I set my **BROADCAST_DRIVER** to log but when i access the link to fire the event, nothing happen. The **laravel.log** file still empty. I already uncomment **BroadcastServiceProvider** on config/app.php. This is my code

**.env**

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=myDatabase
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=numberPassword

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=database

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379
```

**config/app.php**

```
App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class,
App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,
```

**app/Events/ReloadTableEvent.php**

```
class ReloadTableEvent implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    protected $coinData;

    public function __construct($coinData)
    {
        $this->coinData = $coinData;
    }

    public function broadcastWith()
    {
      return ['coin' => $this->coinData];
    }

    public function broadcastAs()
    {
      return 'reload-event';
    }

    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new Channel('reload-channel');
    }
}
```

**app/Http/Controllers/ReloadTableController.php**

```
public function reloadTable()
{
  $coin = Coin::take(50)->get();
  $event = new ReloadTableEvent($coin);
  event($event);
}
```

I already do this

- php artisan config:clear
- php artisan cache:clear
- php artisan optimize
- php artisan clear-compiled
- composer update
- composer dump-autoload

Still nothing. What should i do?

**UPDATE 1**

I'm not using listener yet. When i create new project, and set the same option with my current project, it works.

**storage/log/laravel.log**

```
[2018-01-08 06:24:02] local.INFO: Broadcasting [reload-event] on channels [reload-channel] with payload:
{
    "coin": {
        "name": "Test"
    },
    "socket": null
}
```

Comment: show us your listener

Comment: @Sohel0415 already update my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should listen to the events by `php artisan queue:work`

Comment: I'm not using queue.  When i try the same option with new fresh project, it works and without queue